# Is the chess game from the movie "Revolver" a plausible game?

Tags: film

The movie "Revolver" has a scene with a chess game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI1oSkX-Zag

Is the game plausible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scenes we see in the movie are not completely coherent, some of the things we see are in the wrong order, and the initial chessboard seems to come from the same game, but it is not completely consistent with what happens later. Anyway, the combination they play, with the checkmate, looks like this. Of course the combination is quite simple, and it does not match with the idea they want to give in the movie (the two people are supposed to be tournament players, as we see from the scenes with the chess clocks), so for them this combination would be trivial, and the suspence we see in the last three moves is quite unjustified.

```
[FEN "r1b1r1k1/pp1nbppp/4p3/q2pP3/8/2RBBN2/PP2QPPP/5RK1 w - - 0 1"]


1. Bxh7+ Kxh7 2. Ng5+ Bxg5 3. Qh5+ Kg8 4. Bxg5 Nxe5 5. Rh3 Ng6 6. Qh7+ Kf8
7. Qh8+ Nxh8 8. Rxh8# 1-0
```

Comment: At 3:21 in the video, isn't there a black queen in the neighborhood of g4? How did that get there?

Comment: @DM I see. But at the minute  0:58 we see very well that the black Queen is in a5. At 3:21, it seems it is in f4, but this does not make any sense, Black has no time to move the Queen there. Moreover, at 3:22 also the white Bishop is in the wrong place, in g6 instead of g5, which is totally impossible, we clearly saw the white light squared Bishop being taken by 1...Kxh7. So I would say the scene at 3:21 is very inaccurate.

Comment: All the moves present in my reconstruction can be clearly seen in the movie (in the wrong time order), except for 4.Nxe5 Rh3 5.Ng6, which I inferred from the position black's Knight and white's Rook will have later. The sequence I give is realistic, according to Stockfish they are all best moves, except for 4.Nxe5, where the best move is 4.Qxc3. But a human would usually avoid a move like 4.Qxc3, he'd rather resign if he knows that is the best. So 4.Nxe5 is a reasonable human move.

Comment: I am not sure if a chess analysis is needed here, but after 4...Qxc3! 5.bc3 Nxe5 Black would still be very much in the game.

Comment: @Evargalo   Stockfish evaluates 4...Qxc3 around +6.00 for White. The principal variation is 4...Qxc3 5.bxc3 Nxe5 6.f4 Ng6 7.Rf3 e5 8.f5 Bxf5 9.Rxf5. White's Attack is not over yet, and Black needs to sacrifice a Bishop to avoid it. But probably what you really wanted to say is that a human would play 4...Qxc3, since the loss is not evident. I assumed that giving away the Queen for the Rook would put him down material without really counting! Sorry!